# How to stop Windows firewall from blocking Bonjour hostname resolution

Tags: macos, windows, firewall, hosts, ping

I have Bonjour installed on my Windows 7 PC, and the installer appears to have poked all the necessary holes in the Windows firewall. However, I can't ping windows-pc.local from my Mac. If I completely disable the Windows firewall, I can. How do I configure Windows firewall to allow Bonjour hostname resolution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a new Inbound Rule that allows traffic over UDP port 5353 in the needed security zones.

#### Step-by-step:

1. Open Windows Firewall Advanced Settings

   [image]
2. Create a new rule in Inbound Rules

   [image]
3. Under Protocols and Rules, choose Protocol Type > UDP and Specific Ports > 5353

   [image]
4. Choose the appropriate security zones for your network. For more information on security zones, read the Microsoft documentation: [How Windows Firewall with Advanced Security Works](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722141%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

   [image]

Comment: And how would you do that specifically?

Comment: @patrix I updated the answer with some better documentation.

Comment: Nice indeed____.